# styleframe.ExcelWriter's date_format and datetime_format is not work~

Tags: python, pandas, styleframe

Today I use styleframe to help beautify my Excel.

While I add the date_format or datetime_format, it's not work.

```py
def _write_xlsx(self, filename, data, columns):
    print(f'Writing {filename} length: {len(data)}')

    data_frame = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
    excel_writer = StyleFrame.ExcelWriter(
        filename,
        date_format='YYYY-MM-DD',  # TODO: not work!
        datetime_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS',  # TODO: not work!
    )
    style_frame = StyleFrame(data_frame)
    style_frame.to_excel(
        excel_writer=excel_writer,
        best_fit=columns,
        columns_and_rows_to_freeze='B2',
        row_to_add_filters=0,
    )
    excel_writer.save()
```

I changed the input time object into 'datetime.datetime' or 'Pandas.Timestamp', It's still not working.

```py
pandas.to_datetime(pandas_col.get('my_time')).to_pydatetime()  # datetime.datetime
pandas.to_datetime(pandas_col.get('my_time'))  # Pandas.Timestamp
```

I read styleframe's source code. StyleFrame.ExcelWriter is pandas.ExcelWriter.

pandas.ExcelWriter's **init** func has date_format and datetime_format, and it looks like used date_format and datetime_format.

So, am I have sth. wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`styleframe` uses [`Styler`](https://styleframe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styler.html) objects to represent and apply styles. It can specify different formats for `date`, `time` and `datetime` objects.

See this example:

```py
from styleframe import StyleFrame, Styler

sf = StyleFrame({'a': [datetime.now().date(), datetime.now()]},
                Styler(date_format='YYYY-MM-DD',
                       date_time_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'))
sf.to_excel('dates.xlsx').save()
```

The only oversight is that pandas converts `date` objects to `Timestamp` objects, so the format passed as `date_format` to `Styler` is not used (because internally `styleframe` uses the `date_time_format` for `Timestamp` objects).